# How can I use the iOS Vision framwork from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-vision

The example code on the Apple documentation for [detecting still images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_objects_in_still_images?language=objc) only has Swift example code.

Most tutorials seem to be in Swift and indicate to just "import Vision" in the header, but do not explain how to get the compiler to identify Vision is enabled.

How can I use the Vision framework with Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  In XCode select your target project, under the General tab in the Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content section press the add button.  From there you can add the Vision framework to your project.